# 500 internal error on changing QUERY URL to SEO Friendly URL in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed a php script in a subfolder in my web host and there is a query string that I want it to be changed to SEO friendly URL.

The way it is now:

```
http://example.com/payment/index.php?link=AhYBksPI123
```

and the way I want:

```
http://example.com/payment/AhYBksPI123/
```

I have used some `.htaccess` rules and every time I got 500 internal server error.

**Note:** There is open cart installed in the root folder of the web site and there is no .htaccess file in the root folder and I just put the `.htaccess` file in to the `/payment/` subfolder. Of course, I tested putting `.htaccess` file in to the root folder, but still getting the same error.

This is one of the test codes I have used putting it to the root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /payment/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(?:\.php)?\?link=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=302,L,NE]
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong?!

I don't know if this is the error log that would be useful or not:

> [Tue Dec 08 12:44:11.722999 2015] [core:alert] [pid 2871:tid
>   140185601808128] [client 5.161.54.254:60365]
>   /path/to/root/payment/.htaccess: Invalid command
>   '\xef\xbb\xbfRewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module
>   not included in the server configuration
>
> [Tue Dec 08 12:21:18.328407 2015] [core:alert] [pid 30874:tid
>   140185509488384] [client 5.161.54.254:46771] /path/to/root/.htaccess:
>   Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfRewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or
>   defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Error 500: read the error log of the server.

Comment: I dont have an access to the server. because, I am using a shared web host

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat — If your shared hosting is so bad they won't show you your error logs (this is very unlikely) then you need better hosting.

Comment: Without the error logs it's just guesswork. Things that look strange to me in your .htaccess: Ending the RewriteCond with a whitespace (`\s`), starting the Rule with `^ `.

Comment: Looks like you have some invisible utf8 characters in front of your commands in the .htaccess.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider  I added the error log if its the thing you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfRewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

You have some invisible characters in front of the commands: `\xef\xbb\xbf`. Remove them or, if you can't see them, rewrite the file to make sure they are gone.

Comment: would you please offer a code for me to achieve what I want?! Now, the error is gone and I get 404 error to that link!!!

Comment: I answered the problem of your 500 error. The not working rewrite rules are a different problem, you should open a separate question for it.

Comment: btw, again, the error log is your friend. It will tell you where apache is looking for the files it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /payment

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?link=$1 [L,R=301]
```